# What does the "Q" in "Clock-to-Q delay" stand for?

Tags: clock, register

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the output of stateful elements often named Q?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51625/why-is-the-output-of-stateful-elements-often-named-q)

A register has D (data) as input and Q as output.
What does the Q stand for? I'm having a hard time searching for it.

Answer (score 1):

Q represents the output of a flip-flop or register. For an edge-triggerred flip-flop, the clock-to-Q time is the time it takes for the register output to be in a stable state after a clock edge occurs.

Comment: One nuance: suppose the clock changes at t=0. Clock-to-Q delay is the time d when Q may **start to change**. Q does not necessarily settle at time d.